# Ошибка Неправильный синтаксис около конструкции "LIMIT"

Tags: sql, sql-server

Передаю команду `SELECT * FROM dbo.NewsTable ORDER BY Date LIMIT 2`
Вылетает ошибка "Неправильный синтаксис около конструкции "LIMIT"."
Что я не так пишу?

Comment: Какая база данных?

Comment: @МстиславПавлов, MS sql express

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Инструкция `LIMIT` не поддерживается MSSQL Express, вместо нее вам нужно воспользоваться аналогом: `TOP`.

Пример:

```
SELECT TOP 2 * FROM dbo.NewsTable ORDER BY Date
```

Синтаксис команды:

```
SELECT TOP (top_value) [ PERCENT ]
expressions
FROM tables
[WHERE conditions]
[ORDER BY expression [ ASC | DESC ]];
```

[Тут](https://web.archive.org/web/20210417081325/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/070605-1.shtml) можно найти еще больше способов выбрать N строк.

Comment: так работает, но берет значения первые и сортирует их по дате, а не сортирует по дате, и берет первые два значения